# Iterate through URL ids

Tags: php, iteration

I have a set of urls on the form of

http://www.domain.com/directory/page.php?id=xxxx

How do I iterate through the different ids and save the resulting pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=1;$i<100;$i++)
{
   $results[]=file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/directory/page.php?id=$i");
}
print_r($results);
```

Or if you already have the ids in any array you could loop over them

```
foreach($arrayOfIDS as $id)
{
   $results[]=file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/directory/page.php?id=$id");
}
print_r($results);
```